# Question about the distribution of primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, distribution-of-primes

Let's say that you have two numbers, for example $5,000$ and $10,000$, and we calculate $\pi(5000)$ and $\pi(10000)$. For a number in between them, such as $7,500$, can we do some sort of interpolation to approximate $\pi(7500)$?

Comment: Well, we definitely know that $\pi (5000) \le \pi (7500) \le \pi (10000)$. That's true for any $a,b,c$ with $a\le b\le c$ since $\pi(x)$ is increasing.

Comment: But can we find the value making close agreement with actual value..

Answer (score 1):

Interpolation as if $\pi(x)$ were a linear function will give a fairly good approximation. For example,
$$
\pi(7500) = 950, \quad (\pi(10000) + \pi(5000))/2 = 949
$$ 
and 
$$
\pi(6000) = 783, \quad \frac{4}{5}\pi(10000) + \frac{1}{5}\pi(5000)= 781 \, .
$$ 
This works well because the function $x \mapsto \frac{x}{\log x}$ appearing in the Prime Number Theorem is increasing and concave down, with derivatives going to zero.